# C Language: popen() with fread()?

Tags: c, popen, fread

I've been stuck on this for a few days and it's getting really frustrating.

I'm using `popen()` to call a command line process and get its output and store it in a C string.  I was using `fgets()` but it seems that breaks after a new line, so I'm using `fread()`.  The only problem is that the returned C string is sometimes messed up.

Here's my code:

```
const char *cmd = "date";//This the shell command
char buf[BUFSIZ];//Output of the command
FILE *ptr;
int c;

if ((ptr = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL)
     while(fread(buf, sizeof(buf),1, ptr))
          while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
               printf("output = %s", buf);

(void) pclose(ptr);
```

The final C string sometimes has weird characters in it that shouldn't be there, or sometimes no string is even available.  Can anybody please help? ):

Edit:  Here is what I was doing when using fgets()  The Shell command can be anything that outputs text though.  Not just "date."

`if ((ptr = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL)
while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, ptr) != NULL)
printf("output = %s", buf);
(void) pclose(ptr);`

Answer (score 4):

`fread` doesn't insert a NUL terminator after what it reads. You need to check the return value to know how much it read, and only print that much. If you read with `fread`, you typically want to write the data with `fwrite`, something on this order:

```
long bytes;
while ((bytes=fread(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, ptr))>0)
    fwrite(buf, bytes, 1, stdout);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, `fgets` is the right way to do it.

```
FILE *ptr;

if (NULL == (ptr = popen(cmd, "r"))) {
    /* ... */
}

while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ptr) != NULL) {
    /* There is stuff in 'buf' */
}
```

I think the reason `fgets` wasn't working for you is that you were doing something wrong.

Now, here's why I think you are running into trouble with your current code:

- You are not checking how much `fread` actually returned
- You are reading with `getchar` and discarding stuff
- You don't have a `NUL` terminator in the buffer

Get this right and it will all be better: **`fread` might legally read less than you told it to**.

Comment: fgets() works fine, it just stops after the first line it seems; sometimes the output may be multiple lines

Comment: @Roger O'Brien Show us how you're using `fgets` in this context. Are you doing it in a loop ?

Answer (score 3):

Below is the correct way to use `fread` for process output with `popen`:

```
const char *cmd = "date";
char buf[BUFSIZ];
FILE *ptr;

if ((ptr = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL) {
    /* Read one byte at a time, up to BUFSIZ - 1 bytes, the last byte will be used for null termination. */
    size_t byte_count = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZ - 1, ptr);
    /* Apply null termination so that the read bytes can be treated as a string. */
    buf[byte_count] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}

(void) pclose(ptr);
```

As you can see, the primary problem is to correctly deal with null termination. The two size parameter of `fread` is also important, **you have to let it read character by character** (means that second parameter of `fread` must be 1).

Note that in the case of `popen`, `fread` will only return 0 if the process has exited without giving any output. It will *not* return 0 if it takes a long time for the process to print anything.

If the output is larger than `BUFSIZ`, you can wrap `fread` with a `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The output from `date` doesn't include the `'\0'` (NUL) character you need to properly terminate the string. Keep track of the number of characters read and put in the NUL yourself.

Though really, you should be using `fgets`, [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) or similar text-oriented functions to read from a program such as `date`. `getline` is especially easy (and safe since it does some memory management for you):

```
FILE *fp = popen("date", "r");
char *ln = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

while (getline(&ln, &len, fp) != -1)
    fputs(ln, stdout);
free(ln);
pclose(fp);
```

Comment: getline() is deprecated by my compiler, thank you for your input though

Comment: What compiler is that? `getline` is a POSIX standard function.

Comment: I'm using the built in Mac OS X compiler so I think it's LPNN or GCC

Comment: It won't compile, it says "Implicit declaration of function 'getline' is invalid in C99"

Comment: Then you forgot to include `<stdio.h>`. Or your version of Mac OS X doesn't comply with the latest POSIX.

Comment: The POSIX standard was updated in 2008. Perhaps they still track the 2003 version, or did so in Snow Leopard. Use `fgets` instead.