# Behaviour of uninitialised char array

Tags: c, arrays

I have written a program to practice using `fread`. I am passing a command to `popen` and reading the output using `fread` and storing into an uninitialised char array. Finally I am printing the contents of the array as well as writing it into another file. The print (output in the stdout) works fine but when I check the contents of the file, it has so many junk things after the actual output. Any reason why it works well in stdout?
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fread_s(char *res, int res_size,char *cmd)
{
    char *r;
    int size;
    FILE *fp=popen(cmd,"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
            return;
    size=fread(res,res_size,1,fp);
    pclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
    char cmd[500];
    fread_s(cmd,sizeof(cmd),"ls -lh i*");
    puts(cmd);
    FILE *fp=fopen("opfile","a+");
    if(fp==NULL)
            return;
    fwrite(cmd,sizeof(cmd),1,fp);
}
```

Comment: `fgetss` -> `fread_s`?

Comment: @md5 sorry typo. Edited it.Thanks

Comment: @md5 `fgets()` wouldn't work if `ls` output has newlines in it.

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing the unwanted side effects of a `char` array that is not null terminated. Change:

```
size=fread(res,res_size,1,fp);
```

to

```
size=fread(res,res_size,1,fp);
res[size] = '\0';
```

Also, make sure that `res_size` is one less than `sizeof(cmd)`. Otherwise, you take the chance that `size` is `sizeof(cmd)` and hence,

```
res[size] = '\0';
```

will modify the array using an out of bounds index.

Change

```
fread_s(cmd,sizeof(cmd),"ls -lh i*");
```

to

```
fread_s(cmd,sizeof(cmd)-1,"ls -lh i*");
```

or change

```
size=fread(res,res_size,1,fp);
```

to

```
size=fread(res,res_size-1,1,fp);
```

Comment: `size=fread(res,res_size-1,1,fp);` seems correct, it would make `fread_s()` a pretty inconsistent function to expect: `fread_s(cmd,sizeof(cmd)-1,"ls -lh i*");` meaning it would overwrite the end of the size passed in by 1 char.

Answer (score 2):

Code has `size=fread(res,res_size,1,fp)`, but does not use `size`, which indicates the number of elements read.

The following works even if the data read contains embedded null characters.

```
// Return the number of elements read
size_t fread_s(char *res, int res_size,char *cmd) {
  char *r;
  size_t size;
  FILE *fp = popen(cmd,"r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }
  size = fread(res,res_size,1,fp);
  pclose(fp);
  return size;
}
```

Only write valid number of elements.

```
int main(void) {
    char cmd[500];
    size_t size = fread_s(cmd,sizeof(cmd),"ls -lh i*");

    // puts(cmd);
    fwrite(cmd, size, 1, stdout);

    FILE *fp=fopen("opfile","a+");
    if(fp==NULL) {
            return -1; // Add value to return
    }
    fwrite(cmd, size, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp); // add fclose
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write in standard output, you write a string using `puts`. The string is not null terminated, but there's a strong probability that `puts` encournters a null char in the junk chars. Some junk may be printed, but not all, since a zero can be encoutered.

(this question looks very much like that one, just saw that: [C Language: popen() with fread()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699992/c-language-popen-with-fread))

When you write to your file, you will the whole 500 chars, including junk chars all the way (500 chars)

To get the same behaviour (but still some probable junk):

```
fwrite(cmd,strlen(cmd),1,fp);
```

or

```
fputs(cmd,fp);
```

but you have to null terminate your string after reading the output of `popen`.

Comment: `The null termination ensure that no junk chars are printed afterwards.` where is it null terminated? The suggestions won't because `cmd` isn't null terminated either.

Comment: In this case `cmd` is not null-terminated since `fread()` doesn't null terminate the binary bytes written.

Comment: Okay, you're right. But if there's a null char just after `puts` or not that far, output will stop. Some junk may be visible or not depending how far the zero is.

Comment: I have updated my answer. That could explain the junk not being displayed, but that's mere luck.